# La funcion no me reconoce un Entry que esta creado en una ventana secundaria

Tags: python, tkinter

Cuando intento hacer el *UPDATE* en la función `update`, la consola me informa el siguiente error:

> NameError: name 'modificador' is not defined"
>   Es decir, al pasar de una función a otra, no puedo levantar el texto con la función `get()`
>   ¿Esto tiene algo que ver con que se ha creado el `entry` en una ventana secundaria? He probado de varias maneras y no le encuentro solución. Resumo el código, soy nuevo en esto. Muchas gracias

```
def modificar():
    nueva_ventana=Toplevel(raiz)
    nueva_ventana.geometry("350x270")
    nueva_ventana.title("Modificar")
    nueva_ventana.resizable(0,0)
    modiTitulo=StringVar()
    modiAutor=StringVar()
    modiEditorial=StringVar()
    modiEstado=StringVar()
    label_producto=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Titulo: ")
    label_producto.place(x=30,y=40)
    modificador=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiTitulo)
    modificador.place(x=125,y=40)
    label_etiqueta=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Autor: ")
    label_etiqueta.place(x=30,y=80)
    entry_etiqueta=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiAutor)
    entry_etiqueta.place(x=125,y=80)
    label_editorial=Label(nueva_ventana,text="Editorial:")
    label_editorial.place(x=30,y=120)
    entry_editorial=Entry(nueva_ventana,textvariable=modiEditorial)
    entry_editorial.place(x=125,y=120)
    label_cantidad=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Estado: ")
    label_cantidad.place(x=30, y=160)
    entry_cantidad=ttk.Combobox(nueva_ventana, values=("No leido","Leyendo","Leido"), width=17, state="readonly")
    entry_cantidad.place(x=125, y=160)
    boton_update=tk.Button(nueva_ventana, text="Actualizar datos",command=update)
    boton_update.place(x=150,y=200)
    item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CONTACTOS WHERE NOMBRE='"+item+"'")
    modifica_item=cursor.fetchall()
    for modifica in modifica_item:
        modiTitulo.set(modifica[1])
        modiAutor.set(modifica[2])
        modiEditorial.set(modifica[3])
        modiEstado.set(modifica[4])
    miConexion.commit()

def update():
    item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])
    cursor.execute("UPDATE CONTACTOS SET NOMBRE='"+modificador.get(nueva_ventana)+"', APELLIDO='"+entry_etiqueta.get()+"',DIRECCION='"+entry_editorial.get()+"', TELEFONO='"+entry_cantidad.get()+"' WHERE NOMBRE='"+item+"'")
    miConexion.commit()

raiz=tk.Tk()
raiz.title("Agenda")
raiz.geometry("750x400")
raiz.resizable(0,0)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tienes "modificador" dentro de una función. Cuando sales de la función, las variables que se crean en ella ya no "existen" para el scope global (aunque sí se pueden modificar si fueron creadas afuera). Como "parche" (aunque mala práctica) puedes poner `global modificador` al inicio de ambas funciones. Así se creará una variable global que puede ser llamada desde cualquier parte del código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vamos por partes diría Jack...
primero que nada por que utilizas variables para los label? si esas variables no van a ser llamadas o modificadas a lo largo de toda la ejecución seria mejor que queden como llamadas al modulo de tkinter, por ejemplo:

```
label_producto=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Titulo: ")
label_producto.place(x=30,y=40)
```

no es necesario que tenga una variable de modo que quedaria de forma mas optima:

```
Label(nueva_ventana, text="Titulo: ").place(x=30,y=40)
```

Nos estamos ahorrando lineas de código y hacemos mas legible el mismo.

Otro punto a destacar es que es una mala practica el usar:

`from tkinter import *`

ya que estamos poblando el enterno con nombres que ni siquiera vas a utilizar y cargando todo tkinter para solo usar cosas especificas, entonces lo mejor es utilizar

`import tkinter as tk`

de esta forma cada vez que llames a objeto/widget de tkinter te quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
tk.Label(.....)
tk.Entry(.....)
tk.Tk()
```

con respecto a lo de tu problema como te muestra la consola efectivamente donde esta llamada la variable **modificador**? y si hay muchos widgets que vas a utilizar en en varios modulos tienes dos opciones, o se la pasas como parametro a tus funciones o la declaras como globales siendo esta la opcion menos recomendada

entonces podrías probar con hacer lo siguiente

```
boton_update=tk.Button(nueva_ventana, text="Actualizar datos",command=lambda:update(modificador,entry_etiqueta,entry_editorial,entry_cantidad))
```

en esta primera linea usas la función anónima lambda para pasarle los parámetros a tu función de esa forma ya no debería saltarte que no esta definida, prueba y dime como te va

```
boton_update=tk.Button(nueva_ventana, text="Actualizar datos",command=lambda:update(modiTitulo,modiEstado,modiAutor,modiEditorial))
```

por otro lado pasale el valor de las variables, nose que versión de python usas, pero la 3.8 no deberías de obtener el valor de un Entry si no de la variable directamente

un abrazo y espero pueda servirte mi aporte

Comment: cursor.execute("UPDATE CONTACTOS SET NOMBRE='"+modificador.get()+"', APELLIDO='"+entry_etiqueta.get()+"',DIRECCION='"+entry_editorial.get()+"', TELEFONO='"+entry_cantidad.get()+"' WHERE NOMBRE='"+item+"'")
NameError: name 'modificador' is not defined

Comment: Asi es como me da el error. El asunto es que uso el widgate en otra ventana, que se crea a partir de una funcion, y el UPDATE de la DB se realiza tambien en una funcion, que es diferente a la que crea la ventana que te menciono. Es decir, el update de los datos lo realiza una funcion y el entry esta creado por otra funcion. Creo que por ahi viene la mano. Porque en la ventana principal a la info de los entry me la procesa de lo mas bien.

Answer (score 0):

el error como bien lo menciona @DannyTalent sucede porque cuando llamas a la función *update* que se encuentra en tu *botón update* `command=update` está función intenta procesar está linea:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE CONTACTOS SET NOMBRE='"+modificador.get(nueva_ventana)+"', APELLIDO='"+entry_etiqueta.get()+"',DIRECCION='"+entry_editorial.get()+"', TELEFONO='"+entry_cantidad.get()+"' WHERE NOMBRE='"+item+"'")
```

pero 'modificador' no está definido en esta función, esto lo tienes definido más arriba en la función `modificar()` además estas llamando al método `.get` con un parámetro `modificador.get(nueva_ventana)` y este no lo acepta, te provocará error.

Para que tu ejemplo funcione, deberías modificar la forma en que asignas la función *update* a tu *boton update*, por otro lado, te provocara error cuando llames a grilla puesto que no lo encontré en tu código por lo que asumo que lo tienes definido en otra parte.

Observo también que defines variables para tus *entrys* pero no las estás llamando, simplemente estás intentando obtener el texto aplicando el método `.get` sobre ellos.

Te paso tu mismo código con algunas modificaciones.

```
def modificar(grilla):
    nueva_ventana=Toplevel(raiz)
    nueva_ventana.geometry("350x270")
    nueva_ventana.title("Modificar")
    nueva_ventana.resizable(0,0)

    #variables
    modiTitulo=StringVar()
    modiAutor=StringVar()
    modiEditorial=StringVar()
    modiEstado=StringVar()

    label_producto=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Titulo: ")
    label_producto.place(x=30,y=40)

    modificador=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiTitulo)
    modificador.place(x=125,y=40)

    label_etiqueta=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Autor: ")
    label_etiqueta.place(x=30,y=80)

    entry_etiqueta=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiAutor)
    entry_etiqueta.place(x=125,y=80)

    label_editorial=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Editorial:")
    label_editorial.place(x=30,y=120)

    entry_editorial=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiEditorial)
    entry_editorial.place(x=125,y=120)

    label_cantidad=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Estado: ")
    label_cantidad.place(x=30, y=160)

    entry_cantidad=ttk.Combobox(nueva_ventana, values=("No leido","Leyendo","Leido"), width=17, state="readonly")
    entry_cantidad.place(x=125, y=160)

    boton_update=tk.Button(nueva_ventana, text="Actualizar datos", command= lambda :update(modiTitulo,
                                                                                           modiAutor,
                                                                                           modiEditorial,
                                                                                           entry_cantidad,
                                                                                           grilla))
    boton_update.place(x=150,y=200)

    item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CONTACTOS WHERE NOMBRE=?", item )

    modifica_item=cursor.fetchall()

    for modifica in modifica_item:
        modiTitulo.set(modifica[1])
        modiAutor.set(modifica[2])
        modiEditorial.set(modifica[3])
        modiEstado.set(modifica[4])

    miConexion.commit()

def update(modiTitulo, modiAutor, modiEditorial, entry_cantidad, grilla ):

    item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])

    cursor.execute("UPDATE CONTACTOS SET NOMBRE=?, APELLIDO=?, DIRECCION=?, TELEFONO=? WHERE NOMBRE=?",
                   (modiTitulo.get(), modiAutor.get(), modiEditorial.get(), entry_cantidad.get(), item))

    miConexion.commit()

raiz=tk.Tk()
raiz.title("Agenda")
raiz.geometry("750x400")
raiz.resizable(0,0)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Espero te sirva; hazme saber cualquier duda/inconveniente.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Muchisimas gracias a todos por las respuestas y su dedicación. Lo pude solucionar como bien me marcaron con la función lambda, de la siguiente forma:

```
def modificar():
    item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])
    if item=="":
        messagebox.showinfo("Atencion","Debe seleccionar algun libro")
    else:
        nueva_ventana=Toplevel(raiz)
        nueva_ventana.geometry("350x270")
        nueva_ventana.title("Modificar")
        nueva_ventana.resizable(0,0)
        label_producto=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Titulo: ")
        label_producto.place(x=30,y=40)
        entry_titulo=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiTitulo)
        entry_titulo.place(x=125,y=40)
        label_etiqueta=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Autor: ")
        label_etiqueta.place(x=30,y=80)
        entry_autor=Entry(nueva_ventana, textvariable=modiAutor)
        entry_autor.place(x=125,y=80)
        label_editorial=Label(nueva_ventana,text="Editorial:")
        label_editorial.place(x=30,y=120)
        entry_editorial=Entry(nueva_ventana,textvariable=modiEditorial)
        entry_editorial.place(x=125,y=120)
        label_cantidad=Label(nueva_ventana, text="Estado: ")
        label_cantidad.place(x=30, y=160)
        entry_estado=ttk.Combobox(nueva_ventana, values=("No leido","Leyendo","Leido"), width=17, state="readonly")
        entry_estado.place(x=125, y=160)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM LIBROS WHERE TITULO='"+item+"'")
        modifica_item=cursor.fetchall()
        for modifica in modifica_item:
            modiTitulo.set(modifica[1])
            modiAutor.set(modifica[2])
            modiEditorial.set(modifica[3])
            modiEstado.set(modifica[4])
        miConexion.commit()
        boton_update=tk.Button(nueva_ventana, text="Actualizar datos",command=lambda:update(entry_titulo.get(),entry_autor.get(),entry_editorial.get(),entry_estado.get()))
        boton_update.place(x=150,y=200)

def update(uno,dos,tres,cuatro):
    uno=str(uno)
    dos=str(dos)
    tres=str(tres)
    cuatro=str(cuatro)
    confirmaModifica=messagebox.askyesno(message="¿Esta seguro de que desea modificar?", title="Confirmar")
    if confirmaModifica==True:
        item=str(grilla.item(grilla.selection())['text'])
        cursor.execute("UPDATE LIBROS SET TITULO='"+uno+
            "', AUTOR='"+dos+"',EDITORIAL='"+tres+
            "', ESTADO='"+cuatro+
            "' WHERE TITULO='"+item+
            "'")
        miConexion.commit()
        refrescar()
```